# array of like query for all fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like array('first','12'). So i need to select the table using like condition. which fields have those values.

Example Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE name LIKE '%first%' 
OR father_name LIKE '%first%'
OR age LIKE '%first%'
OR name LIKE '%12%'
OR father_name LIKE '%12%'
OR age LIKE '%12%'
```

I need to find all the fields with or condition. Is this good or have any other options to find an array of values in all fields.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you're trying to reinvent the ORM-wheel here. Just review the existing options, there are plenty.

Comment: what type of engine(myIsam, Innodb) is your table stored in?

Comment: Hi Roman, I have using ENGINE=InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the query using `REGEXP`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM class 
WHERE name REGEXP 'first|12' 
OR father_name REGEXP 'first|12' 
OR age REGEXP 'first|12';
```

Here's the reference:

- [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

And like you said, if you have an array like this,

```
$arr = array('first',12);
```

Then your query should be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE name REGEXP '" . $arr[0] . "|" . $arr[1] . "' OR father_name REGEXP '" . $arr[0] . "|" . $arr[1] . "' OR age REGEXP '" . $arr[0] . "|" . $arr[1] . "'";
```

Comment: Thanks Rajdeep i will try this.

Comment: its return all student list whos father_name is first and return all student age is 12. But i want only whos father_name is first and age is 12

Comment: @Srihari Well, then your query should be like this, `...OR (father_name REGXP 'first' AND age REGXP '12')`. Use parentheses to form conjunctive conditions.